# How can I make a dictionary return keys based on the sum of their values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of:

```
 [['Tameka', '3.5'], ['Esmeralda', '3.9'], ['Katy', '2.7'], ['Lakisha', '3.4'], ['Edwina', '3.0'], ['Darren', '2.9'], ['Rosalinda', '2.8'], ['Margery', '3.1'], ['Kathrine', '3.9'], ['Julio', '4.0'], ['Esmeralda', '4.0'], ['Katy', '3.8'], ['Edwina', '3.2'], ['Darren', '3.8'], ['Rosalinda', '2.9'], ['Margery', '3.2'], ['Kathrine', '3.4'], ['Tameka', '3.6'], ['Julio', '2.0'], ['Katy', '3.0'], ['Lakisha', '4.0'], ['Edwina', '3.7'], ['Darren', '3.7'], ['Rosalinda', '3.8'], ['Margery', '3.5'], ['Kathrine', '2.9'], ['Julio', '3.8'], ['Katy', '4.0'], ['Edwina', '3.6'], ['Darren', '3.8'], ['Rosalinda', '3.7'], ['Margery', '3.9']]
```

and I'm trying to make it so that keys that repeat sum up their values and then return them like so :

```
'Tameka', 'Julio', 'Esmeralda', 'Katy', 'Lakisha', 'Edwina', 'Darren', 'Rosalinda', 'Margery', 'Kathrine'
```

Been stuck on this for a while and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
def dictGpa(cleanList):
    diction = {}
    for item in cleanList:
        if item in diction:
            diction[item] = diction[item.value()]+diction[item.value()]
        else:
            diction[item] = diction[item]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be cleaner to use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for x in cleanList:
    mydict[x[0]] += float(x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists, not dicts. so, use `item.value()` is wrong. it should be `item[0]` for the key and `item[1]` for the value.

```
def dictGpa(cleanList):
        diction = {}
        for item in cleanList:
            if item[0] in diction:
                diction[item[0]] += float(item[1])
            else:
                diction[item[0]]  = float(item[1])
```

Then in `diction` you will have a dict where each name has its final sum.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

this is what I used to change the names and numbers into the list
  
   def cleanGpaList(gpalist):
            mylist = []
             for i in gpalist:
                b = i.strip()
                c = b.split()
                 mylist.append(c)
            return mylist

Comment: in which line are u getting TypeError: unhashable type ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#92>", line 1, in <module>
    dictGpa(cleanGpaList(gpaList))
  File "<pyshell#91>", line 4, in dictGpa
    if item in diction:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Perhaps a good usecase for the setdefault method of a dictionary?

Comment: @EdwardStark you can mark the answer as correct by clicking over the check mark.